# Android selector with image and text

Tags: java, android, button, imagebutton, android-xml

I have a button which I give a color, image and text like this:

```
android:background="@color/green"
android:drawableLeft="@drawable/custom_routes_start_button_icon"
android:text="@string/custom_route_start"
```

This is the unselected state and want the selected state to be something like this:

```
android:background="@color/red"
android:drawableLeft="@drawable/custom_routes_stop_button_icon"
android:text="@string/custom_route_stop"
```

For all I know its not possible to give an item in selector a text or drawableLeft (only drawable). Does anybody know a nice way to achieve this? Maybe another xml file where te selector could refer too?

Comment: try to make a button which have text already

Comment: the background and drawableLeft should be able to use a regular selector (for each). The text could be done by using onTouchListener (change text while down and change back on up)

Comment: What do you mean by "selected"? Do you mean the button has been clicked? Or it has gotten focus?

Comment: The selected state. So when a user clicked it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use two Buttons and only ever show one of them. Use `android:visibility` in XML and `setVisibility()` to show/hide the buttons.

So, at first make the start button visible and hide the stop button. When the user presses the start button, hide the start button and show the stop button. When the user presses the stop button, hide it and show the start button again.

Comment: Oke thanks for the answer. Thats easy to understand but never thought this was the best way to tackle such kind of problem.

Comment: It is :-) The StateSelector drawables are only meant to display different states of one button, e.g. pressed, inactive, etc. but what you want are clearly two buttons. In one of my apps I have exactly what you want - a start and a stop button that are displayed alternately. So I know what I'm talking about ;-)

Answer (score 6):

I'm not sure if ToggleButton(or even checkbox) would fit your use case. You can indeed use selector for your drawable(left,right,top,bottom), use a background with selctor and even different text for your two states.

In effect you can define a selector one for your background (/res/color/custom_color.xml)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:color="@color/green"
          android:state_checked="true" />
    <item android:color="@color/red"
        android:state_checked="false"/>
 </selector>
```

and one for your drawableLeft(/res/drawable/custom_drawable.xml).

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@color/custom_routes_start_button_icon"
          android:state_checked="true" />
    <item android:drawable="@color/custom_routes_stop_button_icon"
        android:state_checked="false"/>
 </selector>
```

and finally your ToggleButton definition as

```
android:background="@color/custom_color"
android:drawableLeft="@drawable/custom_drawable"
android:textOn="@string/custom_route_start"
android:textOff="@string/custom_route_stop"
```

You might have to play with styles to make it appear as you want.

Though this is a late answer,hope someone finds it useful.

Comment: This is the best option. Toggle button solve my problem

Answer (score 1):

you can change this by code:

write below code in xml file:

```
 android:background="@color/green"
 android:drawableLeft="@drawable/custom_routes_start_button_icon"
 android:text="@string/custom_route_start"
```

and on buttonClick event:

```
    yourButton = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.yourButton);

    yourButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Drawable checkImg = getApplicationContext().getResources().getDrawable(
                       R.drawable.custom_routes_stop_button_icon);
            yourButton.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(checkImg, null, null,
            null);
            yourButton.setBackgroundColor(red);
            yourButton.setText(custom_route_stop);
        }
    });
```

you can also place this code onTouchlistener:

```
 yourButton.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
        boolean isTouch = false;

        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                Drawable checkImg = getApplicationContext().getResources().getDrawable(
                       R.drawable.custom_routes_stop_button_icon);
                yourButton.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(checkImg, null, null, null);
                yourButton.setBackgroundColor(red);
                yourButton.setText(custom_route_stop);  
            }
            else {
                Drawable checkImg = getApplicationContext().getResources().getDrawable(
                       R.drawable.custom_routes_start_button_icon);
                yourButton.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(checkImg, null, null, null);
                yourButton.setBackgroundColor(green);
                yourButton.setText(custom_route_start);
            }
            return false;
        }
    });
```

Comment: So which solution is better in ways of programming. Changing drawable, color and text in code (like your solution), or two buttons where only 1 is visible at a time?

Comment: I have implemented one i have writen with programming but as you have wrote, you can also take 2 buttons and use same listener for the both

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean you want to change the button background color if you click the button?
yes you can do it

first define the state

```
private int btnState = 1;
private final static int BUTTON_STATE_SELECTED = 0;
private final static int BUTTON_STATE_UNSELECTED = 1;
```

then set id to your button

```
android:id="@+id/btnRoute"
android:background="@color/green"
android:drawableLeft="@drawable/custom_routes_start_button_icon"
android:text="@string/custom_route_start"
```

declare the button in your activity

```
Button btnRoute = (Button) findviewbyid(R.id.btnRoute);
```

after that create an onclick listener that'll change the button color based on the state

```
private View.OnClickListener mOnClickBtnRoute = new View.OnClickListener() {
switch(btnState) {
case BUTTON_STATE_SELECTED:
btnRoute.setBackgroundColor(green);
btnRoute.setText(start);
Drawable img = getContext().getResources().getDrawable( R.drawable.custom_routes_start_button_icon );
btnRoute.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds( img, null, null, null );
btnState = BUTTON_STATE_UNSELECTED;
break;
case BUTTON_STATE_UNSELECTED:
btnRoute.setBackgroundColor(red);
btnRoute.setText(stop);
Drawable img = getContext().getResources().getDrawable( R.drawable.custom_routes_stop_button_icon );
btnRoute.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds( img, null, null, null );
btnState = BUTTON_STATE_SELECTED;
break;
}
};
```

then don't forget to set the listener to the button

```
btnRoute.setOnClickListener(mOnClickBtnRoute);
```

please remember all the code is coded here so maybe there'll be a mistype so please don't just copy paste but try to understand the concept :) and if you have some question about my answer feel free to ask in the comment!

Comment: But I also want to change the image in the selected state. So not selected is: green, start_image, start_text
Selected is: red, stop_image, stop_text

Comment: yes you can! using setcompounddrawable function please see my edited answer!