# Change button text using <selector>

Tags: android

I am using selector to change color of button. And I was trying to do same with text property.
Is it possible to change text in such way?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/19110306/4870992
check this solution he's using a custom style toggle button ti achieve the performance you're targeting

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As far as I know, you can't do that because `android:text=""` takes string or string resource id as param. If you for example do something like this :

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_focused="true" android:state_pressed="false" android:text="SECOND" />
    <item android:state_focused="true" android:state_pressed="true" android:text="SECOND" />
    <item android:state_focused="false" android:state_pressed="true" android:text="SECOND" />
    <item android:text="FIRST" />
</selector>
```

, like the way we are changing text color or background, it will put the path to this selector as your button text. It will be something like : `res/drawable/text_selector.xml` or whenever you put this file.

So the only way to achieve this is to control it manually in button's `OnClickListener`.

Comment: Yes, its not possible to put selector on text attribute of any view. Be it a Button, TextView, EditText etc.

Comment: How to do that @Khay?